# How can I add selection Python version 3.9 when configuring Python interpreter on Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, conda

I did `conda install python=3.9.7` so now when I run `python` on terminal it will open Python 3.9.7. However, I don't have the option of selecting Python 3.9 on Pycharm when I am trying to create a new Python Interpreter. How can I add the option?

[image]

Comment: What is your pycharm version?

Answer (score 0):

I can provide an answer for Windows 10 setting. You can add the exact version of Python to PyCharm via Conda virtual environment. For that you should:

1. Install the exact version of python to a new Conda virtual env:

   1.1. Open Conda promt **as administrator**

   1.2. `conda create -n my_env_name python=3.9.7`

   1.3. `conda activate my_env_name`
2. (re)open PyCharm
3. Go to File>>Settings>>Python interpreter
4. Add a new interpreter:

   4.1. Press a gear at the right from current interpreter name

   [image: A gear at the right from current interpreter name]

   4.2. Selecct "add"
   4.3. Select "Conda", "Existing environment" and press three dots to add a path to `my_env_name`

   [image: "Conda", "Existing environment" and the three dots]

   4.4. Choose a directory of my_env_name, it should be like

   ```
   C:\Users\yourname\anaconda3\envs\my_env_name
   ```

   4.5. Maybe check the box "Make available to all projects"
   4.6. Press "Ok"
5. Create a new or adit the existing Python configuration:
   5.1 Go to Run>>Edit configurations
   5.2 Add new or edit the existing configuration by choosing `my_env_name` in Python Interpreter field.

   [image: Python Interpreter field]
6. Check that now you are using the right version of python by:
   6.1. Open PyCharm Python Console and run `print(sys.version)`
   6.2. Write some line like `bla-bla-bla = sys.version` in your `.py` file, set the debugger stop after that line, run the debug and check the value of bla-bla-bla variable.

   [image: the value of bla-bla-bla variable]

After you run the code, you will surely get errors of missing packages. You can tell PyCharm to install them by moving PC pointer over the `import <missing_package>` and hitting link "Install package <missing_package>".